# SLURM - sort squeue by job-names

Tags: slurm

Is there a way to get the output of `squeue` ordered by the job-name? I know I can sort, e.g. by job-id via

```
squeue --sort=+i
```

but I don't see how to sort by the job-name (given by #SBATCH --job-name XXX).

Answer (score 4):

As `%j` is the type specification for the job name in `--format` strings, sorting by job name would be

```
squeue --sort=+j
```